# Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data, and node are supported by the default ESM loader Windows Node.js 20.10

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to replicate [this](https://github.com/TomasBorquez/Discord-Bot-TTS-STT)  discord bot project. I am encountering an error when I try to import the registerCommands and loadCommands functions from commands.js.

```
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Events } from 'discord.js';
import { registerCommands, loadCommands} from './commands.js';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, // These are the permissions the bot has
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
  ],
});

registerCommands(); // Register all commands

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
  loadCommands(interaction)
});

// Login bot
dotenv.config();
client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Here is the error.

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" 
C:Users\user\documents\projects\Discord-Bot-TTS-STT\index.js
node:internal/modules/esm/load:236
    throw new ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME(parsed, schemes);
          ^

Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data, and node are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'
    at throwIfUnsupportedURLScheme (node:internal/modules/esm/load:236:11)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:128:3)
    at ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:409:13)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:291:56)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:65:26)
    at #createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:303:17)
    at ModuleLoader.getJobFromResolveResult (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:260:34)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:241:17)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:328:23) {
  code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME'
}

Node.js v20.10.0
```

I have tried to use require statements and tried to use url.pathToFileURL but I get a similar error or another saying the module cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

In `commands.js` file author used some trick to import commands,

```js
      const command = await import(commandPath);
```

I think you should try something like

```js
      const command = await import("file://"+commandPath);
```

Also this project uses `.env` file,
in the project directory create an `.env` file with those contents

```
DISCORD_TOKEN=ABCDEFGH
CLIENT_ID=1234567890
OPENAI_TOKEN=ABCDFGH
```

Comment: Perhaps I was not specific enough. I edited the post. I have the .env set up properly. The error only happens when trying to import commands.js on line 2.